# Either the user, 'IIS APPPOOL\App Name', does not have access to the 'SSAS Cube Name' database, or the database does not exist

Tags: iis, permissions, ssas, ssms, database-administration

1st - I deployed the cube to localhost using SSAS (SQL Server Analysis Services)

2nd - I verified the cube database exists using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) even tough the [SSAS DB is not showing in SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510126/ssas-db-not-visible-in-management-studio-but-can-be-seen-in-excel)

3rd - I tried to grant permission to my IIS APPPOOL following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665250/how-can-i-grant-permissions-to-a-database-for-the-iis-app-pool-account)

4th - I added a new connection in SSMS to Analysis Services in localhost server (instead of a connection to the database engine in the localhost server)

5th - I realized that the process for granting permissions is different for relational databases and multidimensional databases and the previous answer would not work, so I followed microsoft docs to [grant cube or model permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/grant-cube-or-model-permissions-analysis-services)

6th - I tried finding some identifier of the IIS process to add in the role I created in step 5. I did not find any and have no idea what to do to grant access to the ISS process, so I went ahead and tried connecting to the cube database again without success.

7th - I tried changing the connection string to include password for the sa user of the database. Still no luck.

I am taking too long with this issue so decided to post question to stackoverflow while I continue my efforts to solve it. Thanks for any help/pointers to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

1 - Connect to Analysis Services server where the multidimensional model is deployed.

2 - Databases->SSAS(*) Solution Name->Roles

3 - [Grant cube or model permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/grant-cube-or-model-permissions-analysis-services) by creating a new role

4 - In membership, Add->Advanced. Click Find Now, select IUSR and IIS_IUSRS, click ok all the way. **Note:** Maybe only IIS_IUSRS is required.

*SQL Server Analysis Services